# How does 'net use' command work with different users and different processes

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, operating-systems, jenkins

Recently, I wrote a python script to do some routine file manipulation and maintenance for a folder on a shared network drive (one that requires authentication to access).

When I ran the the script on my local machine, it worked and was able to access the network drive no problem. Then I put the script on a remote machine and had Jenkins  run it. Jenkins was giving me an access denied error because Jenkins was installed as a service run by the local system account which did not have access to the shared drive.

So, after looking for solutions I saw that I could use the net use command to gain network access with other credentials. I tried writing a powershell script that used net use, with my login info passed, to call the python script.

This did not work.

Finally, I tried using the net use command within the python script using os.sys('net use user/pass') and it worked!

So, my question is.. why did it work when the net use command was placed within the python script but not within the powershell script used to invoke the python one?

Most of what I read about 'net use' online describes it for 'mapping' to a network drive? But my computer already knew the drive existed and where it was it just did not have access to it until I passed in a username and password with the command. What is the scope of the network authentication from this command? Do child processes not keep that same authentication?

Comment: Could the Jenkins service be configured to use a user account which would then have access to the share drive? My first thought for the problem as described was the EnableLinkedConnections registry key.  For example, by default, if you map a drive in a command prompt, you can't see it in an elevated command prompt unless the EnableLinkedConnections registry key is set.  I wonder if this could be part of what you're seeing without knowing all the details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the registry key. I shall look into that. Just to be clear, I have it working now by calling the net use command within the python script. I am just trying to understand why the other way didn't work. As for the other suggestion, I maybe could have had the Jenkins service run as my own user account instead of the system, but that seemed like a bad idea to me because other people running Jenkins could do things under my accounts credentials.

Comment: Could you create a dedicated service account to use rather than your account?